# What is this mystery function that wolfram alpha says my exponential generating function is equal too?

Tags: number-theory, generating-functions, hypergeometric-function

The $E_n(x^n)$ is the mystery function

$$\sum_{d=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{dn}}{\Gamma(dn+1)}=E_n(x^n)$$

Here are the first 3 values of the function

[image]

Comment: How about 
$$E_n(x^n) = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \exp\left(x e^{2 \pi i k/n} \right)$$

Comment: Thats excellent, can you cite your source? Thanks.

Comment: If $F(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} a_k x^k$, then, completely formally,

$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} a_{nk} x^{nk} = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} F(x e^{2 \pi i k/n}).$$

For this (and much more) see https://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/gfology2.pdf, in particular (for this example) the discussion starting the second last paragraph of page 50 (around formula 2.4.4).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the [Mittag-Leffer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mittag-Leffler_function) generalization of the exponential function.

Comment: Thank you. That saved me so much time.

Answer (score 0):

For $$E_n=\sum_{d=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{dn}}{\Gamma(dn+1)}$$ the first terms are simple
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & E_n \\
 1 & e^x \\
 2 & \cosh (x) \\
 3 & \frac{2}{3} e^{-x/2} \cos \left(\frac{\sqrt{3} x}{2}\right)+\frac{e^x}{3} \\
 4 & \frac{\cos (x)}{2}+\frac{\cosh (x)}{2}
\end{array}
\right)$$ For $n>4$, they are hypergeometric functions
$$E_5=\, _0F_4\left(;\frac{1}{5},\frac{2}{5},\frac{3}{5},\frac{4}{5};\frac{x^5}{5^5}\right)$$
$$E_6=\,
   _0F_5\left(;\frac{1}{6},\frac{2}{6},\frac{3}{6},\frac{4}{6},\frac{5}{6};\frac{x^6}{6^6
  }\right)$$
$$E_7=\,
   _0F_6\left(;\frac{1}{7},\frac{2}{7},\frac{3}{7},\frac{4}{7},\frac{5}{7},\frac{6}{7};
   \frac{x^7}{7^7}\right)$$ and the pattern is quite clear.